# Does the US economy's future depend on equilibrium?

Tags: economy

In social dictatorships (real name of what you would refer to as communism) people do not work hard enough cause they lacked the prospective of growth. That's where you need capitalism.

So but then the problems arise when capitalism goes on for too long, and wealth becomes concentrated too much to the Elite. The poor will be predetermined to fail to endless poverty by being born to a ghetto neighborhood. So both are the end of the scale. The solution is something in between. That would be capitalism with huge taxes on the wealthy's income and bank accounts.

Money in modern economy is like blood in the body. If it gets stuck somewhere or concentrates too much at a certain place it makes you sick. This is the same as in the US economy where money is too much concentrated with the Elite. Money, or at least most of it is not flowing back to the lower 90% of the society. Elite starts to live in secluded neighborhoods. The rest of the territory becomes ghetto-like, low income families, crime, unsafe. Low quality education etc.

The current economic crisis is based on these facts:

1. the current economic system was mainly developed by Keynes as "new deal" after WWII.
2. It basically said that in economic downturn, the government has to step in and do government-purchases, huge investments like (build a dam, reactor roads infrastructure etc.) that will drive the economy, create jobs , create more demand etc.
3. back then the economy was mostly product-based
4. since then the economy turned to mostly service-based
5. Keynes method does not work anymore effectively since government cannot do huge purchases in one. (they cannot order 5Million manicure-s)
6. government cannot handle the economic downturn, just shovel it under the rug.
7. we have a huge real-unemployment rate. But the people who do not want to look for a job are not part of the currently viewed unemployment rate. These are the people who get social benefits (foodstamps).
8. the number of effective employed and working people are many less then it should be, thus the economy's output is not effective.
9. in this service based ineffective output economy economic stability is based on consumer confidence.
10. consumer confidence is based on the money available for spending and the future expectation of it.
11. The only way to increase the available money for spending would be to give more income to the working people. Thus increase spending, demand and consumption, employment etc.
12. the top 10% of the nation possesses over 90% of bank account money in the US currently. The lower 90% has only 10% of the money.

So what would be the way to provide more money to spend for the consumers in a long term sustainable way given the current circumstances in the US? Can it be done by reallocating the bank account money's to create some sort of equilibrium and drive the economy by giving money to spend for the lower 90%? That would drive spending, consumption more jobs etc. The Elite of course would have to accept that in a way that they give some of their money to the lower classes for spending, but logically they, the elite are the business owners, so they would just drive this way more consumption to their own businesses, so they could make up for it, let's say in 5 years of tax deductions? Or any other solution?

Comment: Provide Citation for your 12 facts; your premise is substantially weaker for being based on unfounded suppositions.

Comment: I think your question is better suited on [Economics Beta SE](http://economics.stackexchange.com/). As @DrunkCynic commented, you need to ask your question based on some references. Good luck.

Comment: why did i get minus 8 points on this question?

Answer (score 3):

> the current economic system was mainly developed by Keynes as "new deal" after WWII.

The [New Deal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Deal) was Franklin D. Roosevelt's rebranding of his former opponent Hoover's proposals from the election of 1932.  It was before World War II, not after.  Also, the New Deal was specific to the Great Depression.  Most of those programs disappeared afterwards.

The New Deal was a Keynesian stimulus, but it certainly isn't the basis of the post-WWII economy.

> Keynes method does not work anymore effectively since government cannot do huge purchases in one. (they cannot order 5Million manicure-s)

Keynes was not trying to increase consumption except in the sense that a more robust economy would consume more.  Keynes was trying to increase investment.  This is why he suggested that government invest in things like road projects during a recession.

The biggest problem with Keynes' proposals is that governments only half-implement them.  Contrary to popular belief, Keynes favored not just balanced budgets but surpluses under normal circumstances.  He only favored deficits in the specific case of combating a recession.  Governments are happy enough to run bigger deficits when in recessions, but they never seem to run the surpluses to pay them off during the boom times.

Services versus products don't matter, as Keynes didn't advocate buying either directly.  In his suggestion, the government would do a combination of direct investment in things like new roads or bridges, tax cuts, and anti-poverty programs to keep people alive (unemployment insurance, food stamps, etc.).  In turn, the construction workers, taxpayers, unemployed, and farmers would have money to spend.  It's that money that drives consumption.  Those people would buy the five million manicures or whatever.  Not the government.

Comment: "Services versus products don't matter," this is not true.  " Those people would buy the five million manicures or whatever. Not the government." this is misleading too. Back then, the economy was production based. So 70% of the GDP was mage up of roads building, etc. The government could easily add some investments. Nowadays that just does not work. The economy is now service based, 70%. Products are only 30%. To create consumption, the government back then could easily order a new dam to be built. Now the only way to drive consumption and demand is to order services.

Comment: but those are made up of millions of small orders. Government cannot substitute them. The only way is to give the people money to spend. They will consume. Why did I get 8 minuses on this question with a masters in economics, when people do not have basic academic knowledge, this is nonsense.

Comment: "Back then, the economy was production based. So 70% of the GDP was mage up of roads building, etc."  Very little of the economy has ever been road building.  Road building is almost exclusively government spending.  In [1932](http://federal-budget.insidegov.com/l/34/1932), 7% of GDP was federal government spending.  And only 10% of that was transportation.  So roughly $6 billion.  In 2016 dollars, that's almost $100 billion.  It's about $90 billion now.  And overall, government is a larger portion of GDP now than in 1932.  Over 40%.

Comment: by production based I mean whjat it means in economics. It means in economics that it is not service based. Since the economy can output the GDP in two ways only mainly. Products and services. Back then, the value of the GDP was 70%made up of creating products and only 30% of creating services. Now it is the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

> the current economic system was mainly developed by Keynes as "new
>   deal" after WWII.

Keynes developed a political economic strategy not an economy.  However, Keynes has been largely disproved though implementation of his policies. The vast majority of serious economists dismiss him when discussing practical and effective policy decisions.

> back then the economy was mostly product-based since then the economy
>   turned to mostly service-based

Not really.  The economy is a multifaceted and multi-threaded entity, but product purchases are still the benchmark for the evaluation of the health of the economy.

> Keynes method does not work anymore effectively since government
>   cannot do huge purchases in one. (they cannot order 5Million
>   manicure-s) goverment cannot handle the economic downturn, just shovel
>   it under the rug. 7. we have a huge real-unemployment rate. But the
>   people who do not want to look for a job are not part of the currently
>   viewed unemployment rate. These are the people who get social
>   benefits(foodstamps).

This statement shows a grave understanding of reality of the situation.  Most of those that have fallen out of the employment figures have taken to doing things outside of the standard employment model.  From odd jobs, scrapping, repurposing for resale, and things like driving for Uber, or dog walking.  Some of them may qualify for food stamps but even that would benefit a Keynesian model economy.  But the actual cost of the benefit is so small in the scheme of the budget that it is not a battle worth fighting, and it has little to no effect on the overall economy.

> the top 10% of the nation possesses over 90% of bank account money in
>   the US currently. The lower 90% has only 10% of the money.

This is grossly false.

First the really wealthy do not keep their money in bank accounts.  They invest their wealth in more profitable options like Hedge funds, real estate, stocks, Art, etc.

Even when you look at income breakdown the top 10% still only makes about 25-30% of the income for a given year.  And that is looking at gross incomes not net, where the number drops to around 15%.

Comment: i said " economic system" not economy.

Comment: This is "product purchases are still the benchmark for the evaluation of the health of the economy". a complete nonsense. 70% of the current US economy is consumption based that is mostly depending on services. Not products. And again almost 70% of the GDP's value is comprised of services. Products only make maybe 30%. That is just statistics. I do Not understand why you are voting my question down giving me munis reputation.

Comment: "This is grossly false.
First the really wealthy do not keep their money in bank accounts"

Comment: I said of the health of an economy.  Many experts are predicting imminent collapse of the US Economy.  And where do you get your figures that 70% of the economy is consumption of services?

Comment: Again you are wrong. I was only talking about the bank account's money (checking,savings). That is allocated 90-10 as I said. Simple statistics. What you are talking about is other kinds of financial investments (I have a master's in finance I think I should know). That might have an even worse allocation, since the poor 90% don't even have other kind's of financial investments mostly. A third thing is real estate. You are completely mixing up even real estate with financial assets. So there are basically two types. 1. financial assets. 2. non-financial assets.

Comment: The group 1. has 1a). money on bank accounts (checking savings as I said), and 1b) other types of financial assets. Group 2 has also different types of assets like real estate, cars, yachts etc. As I said group 1a) has statistically a 90-10 allocation, just a fact. And that is what is causing the real problem. The other 1b) and 2) group has an even worse allocation, over 99-1 unfortunately. That causes housing abuse.

Comment: I really don't get the point of being downgraded on my question so much, losing reputation, now I cant even ask or answer I think.

Comment: service-based statistics: What percentage of the US economy is service?
Domestic and International Importance.
The services sector is an important part of the U.S. economy. According to BEA, in 2009 services accounted for 79.6 percent of U.S. private-sector gross domestic product (GDP), or $9.81 trillion.

Comment: In 1939 the services to manufacturing employment ratio was 2.1:1. Today it is 9.9-to-1. source:http://www.businessinsider.com/growth-of-us-services-economy-2014-9

Comment: If you have some sources you can link in your question that would be much better than chatting here.

Comment: *employment ratio was 2.1:1. Today it is 9.9-to-1.* - yes and the headline today: http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-10-12/hsbc-there-s-now-a-very-high-chance-of-a-severe-fall-in-u-s-stocks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_the_United_States             GDP by sector
Agriculture: 1.6%
Industry: 20.8%
Services: 77.6%
(2015)[5]

Comment: Where is your source on the bank accounts though.

Comment: http://www.census.gov/people/wealth/

Comment: HOUSEHOLD NET WORTH Savings Interest Earning Assets at Financial Institutions Special savings Other Interest- Earning Assets Regular Checking Accounts
LOWER 90% Negative or zero 2,482 - 1,014
 $1 to $4,999 972 - 548
 $5,000 to $9,999 1,965 - 1,085
 $10,000 to $24,999 3,397 - 1,460
TOP 10% $25,000 to $49,999 5,696 - 1,681
 $50,000 to $99,999 8,286 - 2,333
 $100,000 to $249,999 13,894 13,583 3,094
 $250,000 to $499,999 30,158 40,811 3,861
 $500,000 and over 70,380 1,371,630 7,305

Comment: Net worth is not the same as savings.  yes the wealthy are not in debt... that is a common trait.

Comment: this is only for checking and savings

Comment: Actually it is savings less loans and lines of credit